# How do i install python 3.5?

Tags: updates, python, 15.10

I think installed python 3.5, i have the python 3.5 idle3 on my desktop, but when i write in the the command

```
python -- version
```

the output is 2.7.0.1. How do i actually upgrade it to 3.5

Comment: Run `python3 --version`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add this ppa  https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes This one has the latest 3.5 version